# Send email to multiple recipients with Python and O365

Tags: python-3.x, office365

I need to send email to multiple recipients however it is being received by only one receiver. Below is my code that I am using.

```
from O365 import Message

o365_auth = ('user.com', 'Pwd')
m = Message(auth=o365_auth)
m.setRecipients('user1.com','user2.com')
m.setSubject('abc found.')
m.setBody('''abc found.'

Regards
Shashi S Singh''')
m.sendMessage()
```

However once triggered it is sending email only to the first recipient whereas expectation is to send email to both recipients.

Comment: Does it work if you set the emails together in one string? `m.setRecipients('user1.com,user2.com')`

Comment: Thanks ode2k but I already tried this with no success..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from O365 import Message

recipients=['user1.com','user2.com']#create a list of recipients
o365_auth = ('user.com', 'Pwd')
m = Message(auth=o365_auth)
m.setRecipients(recipients)#use the list created
m.setSubject('abc found.')
m.setBody('''abc found.'

Regards
Shashi S Singh''')
m.sendMessage()
```

Creating a list and using the same did the trick.

Comment: Do you know how to send a message to a recipient, using the "cc" field?

Comment: @Milton `m.addRecipient('bob@loblaw.com', r_type="Cc")` or `m.addRecipient('bob@loblaw.com', r_type="Bcc")` should do it